# Permutations In PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm still new to scripting. But I have made a script that determines if 2 checkboxes are checked or unchecked. whether or not those 2 options are checked or unchecked produces 4 possible outcomes.
Either, both are Checked; both Un-Checked; Option1 Checked and Option2 Un-Checked; or Option 1 Un-Checked and Option 2 Checked.

This is Shown Below,

```
function StartBatch{
    if($CheckBoxObject1.Checked -eq $true -and $CheckBoxObject2.Checked -eq $true){
        Start-Process -FilePath "Resources\Scripts\BothChecked.bat" -ArgumentList "/c","dir","."
    }
elseif ($CheckBoxObject1.Checked -eq $false -and $CheckBoxObject2.Checked -eq $false){
        Start-Process -FilePath "Resources\Scripts\BothUnChecked.bat" -ArgumentList "/c","dir","."
        }
elseif ($CheckBoxObject1.Checked -eq $true -and $CheckBoxObject2.Checked -eq $false){
        Start-Process -FilePath "Resources\Scripts\1Checked2UnChecked.bat" -ArgumentList "/c","dir","."
        }
elseif($CheckBoxObject1.Checked -eq $false -and $CheckBoxObject2.Checked -eq $true){
        Start-Process -FilePath "Resources\Scripts\1UnChecked2Checked.bat" -ArgumentList "/c","dir","."
        }
    }
```

Using a Combinations and Permutations Calculator, I Determined that if I added Another Checkbox, It Would Bump up the possible outcomes to 8, as shown:

```
1 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 2 options
2 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 4 options
3 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 8 options
4 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 16 options
5 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 32 options
6 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 64 options
7 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 128 options
8 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 256 options
9 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 512 options
10 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 1024 options
11 checkboxes = Number of permutations: 2048 options
```

So to Sum up my Question, How can I Write all of these possible outcomes WITHOUT adding in Say 2048 Unique Lines of Code for the 11 checkboxes, whilst still giving it enough logic to determine if the final outcome has those options selected.
I.E.
If I had 11 checkboxes, What would be the proper way to write that in powershell without adding a few thousand if -and or ifelse statements, while maintaining those 2048 options in memory. I hope I'm explaining that correctly and makes sense to someone.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a single batch script and just pass the states of the checkboxes as arguments to it? `checked.bat 0 0`, `checked.bat 0 1`, `checked.bat 1 0`, `checked.bat 1 1`, etc.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it matters which boxes are checked vs not, so why not instead just count how many are checked/unchecked and react based off those counts?   Or are you really going to have individual bat files for each scenario?  And regarding that, are the batch files really necessary?  Why not just do everything in the powershell script?

Comment: Yeah, just for the sake of learning I'd like to imagine I had 2048 individual batch files that had different operations to be taken for each scenario depending on clicked or unclicked. I'm not sure how i would go about passing an argument to a batch file, but even then wouldn't I still have to write every possible outcome in the batch file. Is there no logic for this?

Comment: Daniel I guess that makes more sense to Tally them up, idk why I didn't think of that. I was gonna make a game of sorts where depending on which option you click the story unfolds differently... The game being more less a story with different optional outcomes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go...

My answer is comprised of two parts. In the first part I want to tell you that your explanation about the number of permutations that are generated by the number of checkboxes is *exactly the same explanation* than the number (of options, or permutations) that are generated by the number of bits when the "checkboxes array" is taken as a number written in [binary system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).

Lets review such a system with just 8 bits (or checkboxes):

```
Bit (or checkbox):   8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
Value:             128 64 32 16  8  4  2  1
```

Each configuration of checkboxes turned on/off generate an unique number; for example, all checkboxes turned off (00000000) is the number 0. All checkboxes turned on (11111111) is the number 255. From 0 to 255 there are 256 different numbers (permutations). In this way, each different permutation of 8 checkboxes (bits) turned on/off generate an unique number from 0 to 255.

Let's pass now to the second part...

---

This means that you can identify each configuration of checkboxes via a number. Now the part I don't understand is this: What you want to do with each one of these numbers? Let's start with a simple example (written as variables in Batch .bat file):

```
set "option[0]=BothUnChecked"
set "option[1]=1UnChecked2Checked"
set "option[2]=1Checked2UnChecked"
set "option[3]=BothChecked"
```

These *array* variables obtain an equivalent result of your PS example code above.

Now, what you want to do with the rest of options when the number of checkboxes is greater than 2? I think you should comprehend what this point means...

---

*Addendum*:

For example, instead of "BothUnChecked" you could use the number `0`, and instead of "BothChecked" you could use the number `3`. In the same way, instead of create names with "Checked" and "UnChecked" words combined with the number of each checkbox, why not just use the *direct* number of each permutation of checkboxes (in binary)?

For example, with 11 checkboxes you could have 2048 Batch files named "File0.bat", "File1.bat", ... up to "File2047.bat" and, to select the appropriate one, just follow this procedure:

- Get the on/off status of the 11 checkboxes as 11 bits with values 1/0.
- Convert these 11 bits from binary to decimal (this is very simple to do).
- Use the resulting decimal number to directly call the "File0.bat" ... "File2047.bat"

---

However, IMHO you don't need such a high number of different Batch files. You could have a single Batch file that receive a number and then process the 11 different status that each one of the checkboxes means. To do that, just take the received number, separate such a decimal number in individual bits where each bit represent a checkbox (this is very simple to do), and finally process each bit/checkbox...

Comment: Thank you for the Reply, I'm not gonna lie this is all still very confusing to me... but you've helped me understand it a little bit better. I'm no doubt going to have to review this answer for a while until I fully grasp the idea of arrays and other things you've mentioned. Really appreciate the responce, and fast too!

Comment: See the "addedum" in my answer...

Comment: Starting with the premise that you *have* to use 2048 batch files, I’d probably use the binary convention for the file names - e.g. ```file00000000.bat``` so they sort in more logically and are easier to work out the name for given a combination of checkbox values when trying to maintain them.